# Visual Studio unmanaged C++ smart file explorer

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I use Visual Studio to develop unmanaged C++ apps for a living.

Is there an add-on tool (price isnt the issue) that is smart enough to detect folders that I create within my solution folder and add them to the include path (/I)? It would automatically do this for win32, or x64 platform settings, or debug, and release, etc.

It should also be smart enough to remove the include paths if folder is deleted

Arent you frustrated sometimes when you double click a file under solution explorer and Visual Studio says it cant find the file because somebody moved or renamed it? ---> Is there a tool that would periodically scan the files in Solution Explorer and automatically removes or prompts the user to let them know those files are no longer valid?

Like John Lakos once said, I too would pay for an add-on that can automatically add #include  into my code by just parsing my project's .h/.cpp files.

When is Visual Studio going to have an Eclipse-like solution explorer that allows user to directly manipuate the files/folders structure directly from within Visual Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* manipulate files/folders from the IDE! Just click the "show all files" button in the solution explorer (2nd from left, at the top). I just recently found that out.

Comment: okay..i clicked on show all files, but it shows all the files within my project. But it doesnt show any folders. Or am I mistaken.

Comment: oh you know what, never mind. I think old project wouldnt work like you described. However, I found that if I created a new project, it works fine. thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem, I found that out recently, and it's great.